# What nuance does ガールフレンド have?

Tags: word-choice, meaning, loanwords

Does ガールフレンド have a meaning of a female friend (like [girl friend](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/girl_friend)), or a female romantic partner?

Someone told me it had the former meaning, and I should use "彼女" for a romantic partner. However, the Japanese edition of Wikipedia seems to imply that [ガールフレンド](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%AC%E3%83%BC%E3%83%AB%E3%83%95%E3%83%AC%E3%83%B3%E3%83%89) means romantic partner, as does the [Tanaka corpus](http://jisho.org/sentences?jap=%E3%82%AC%E3%83%BC%E3%83%AB%E3%83%95%E3%83%AC%E3%83%B3%E3%83%89). Neither the English nor Japanese edition of Wiktionary have an entry on ガールフレンド.

Comment: Strange as it may sound, but this is the most difficult question that I have encountered on here.  It is SO complicated.

Answer (score 7):

彼女 is the word you want to use. Use of ガールフレンド is very uncommon now and would sound a bit like a misguided effort by an old person to sound hip, or something. If you use it though, it will mean romantic partner. To refer to female friends, people use 女友達.

Comment: +1, but my curiosity has been piqued by Tokyo Nagoya's comment, and I'm hoping someone will provide a more detailed answer.

Answer (score 4):

Without doubt, the most common ways to directly express "lover" in spoken Japanese are 彼女, 彼氏, 恋人, 付き合っている人, etc.

「ガールフレンド」 is a misleading word even for native Japanese, and it stands somewhere between "100% lover" and "100% pure female friend without romantic feelings". And I agree that "ガールフレンド" is seldom used in modern spoken Japanese, maybe because it's long and also ambiguous.

However I don't think this word is dead nor old-fashioned; you may have seen by googling that there is actually a famous and popular smartphone game named "ガールフレンド（仮）" published very recently. I think the current practical use of ガールフレンド is express 恋人 euphemistically, or to emphasize the sense of chastity or platonic relationship compared to directly saying 恋人.